# Как определить последний элемент в listview yii2?

Tags: php, yii2

Как в itemView передать либо количество всех элементов dataProvider, либо узнать последний ли это элемент?

В itemView выводится по два блока div.row по условию открывающийся тег `if (($index + 1) % 2 === 1)`, закрывающий тег div - `if (($index + 1) % 2 === 0)`
Сейчас для 3 элемента не закрывается блок div, поэтому плывет верстка.

Как правильно реализовать?

```
ListView::widget([
                        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
                        'itemOptions' => [
                            'tag' => false,
                        ],
                        'layout' => "{items}\n{pager}\n{summary}",
                        'itemView' => function ($model, $key, $index, $widget) {
                            return $this->render('_item', compact('model', 'key', 'index','widget'));
                        },
                   
                    ]);
                    ?>
```

```
<?php if (($index + 1) % 2 === 1) { ?>
<div class="row">
    <?php } ?>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <article class="blog_style1 small">
            test
        </article>
    </div>
    <?php if (($index + 1) % 2 === 0) { ?>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У `dataProvider`  есть метод `getTotalCount`, который даст количество всех записей. В `$index` идёт индекс записи в массиве. То есть, если `$index === $dataProvider->getTotalCount() - 1` - значит последняя запись

Comment: а как передать dataProvider в itemView?

Comment: @ОльгаМаксакова как и во всех анонимных функциях: через `use ($valiable)`. Но рекомендую в контроллере сформировать переменную `totalCount` и уже её передавать, чтобы миллион раз не вызывать один и тот же метод у провайдера